# $f \mapsto f(0)$ is not continuous on $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Show that the the linear map $f \mapsto f(0)$ is not a continuous on $L^2(\mathbb{R},m)$.

In order to show that the map $L^2(\mathbb{R}) \ni f \mapsto f(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ is not continuous, it suffices to show that there exists $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ so that the mapping is not continuous at $f$. Let $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ wlog assume that either $-\infty < f(0) < \infty$ or $f(x) = \infty$. Define

$$g_n(x) = \begin{cases}
f(x)-\sqrt{n} \quad \, : \, x \in [-\frac{1}{2n^2}, \frac{1}{2n^2}] \\
f(x) \quad \,  : \, \text{ else }
\end{cases}.$$

Then,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\| f-g_n \|_{L^2} = \int_\mathbb{R} |f-g_n|^2 \, dm &=& \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left|\sqrt{n} \chi_{[-\frac{1}{2n^2}, \frac{1}{2n^2}]} \right|^2 \, dm \\
&=& \frac{1}{n}.
\end{eqnarray*}
 \
Now, let $\epsilon = 1$, then for any $\delta > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that, if $n \geq N$, $$\|f-g_n\|_{L^2} < \delta$$ but  $$|f(0) - g_n(0)| >1.$$ Therefore the mapping is not continuous at $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$, as desired.

Any issues here? Dear Downvote, I know this problem is not well-defined, but it's homework.

Comment: The mapping is not even well defined as $f\in L^2$ is really an equivalent class of functions.

Comment: @JohnMa Yeah we told our professor that haha, he said just pretend nonetheless

Comment: @uniquesolution Ah I see. Is it correct as is?

Comment: Oh my goddess..... OK ^^.

Comment: @JohnMa I know it's odd..he said just pretend you can pick a single function as a representative and fix it

Comment: The problem is then I can pick the representative in such a way that $f(0) = 0$ for all $f$, and so the mapping is continuous....

Comment: @JohnMa Yes indeed haha....he admitted it was not his best problem writing, but it makes for a decent enough exercise, just to work with some estimates and what not

Comment: @JohnMa actually has a point here.

Comment: @uniquesolution of course he does, the mapping isn't well-defined :)

Comment: Yes, therefore the entire question is useless and a waste of time.

Comment: @uniquesolution Well maybe that's a tad harsh. But I *have* to do it. It's an assigned homework problem

Comment: I would change my professor, if I were you. This is a low-quality mathematical education.

Comment: This question is really a bit hard to make sense of......

Comment: @uniquesolution I think it was just a mistake on his part. He's a young post-doc from Berkeley, and it's his first time teaching a Grad Analysis/Funct Analysis course. Also, it's a very highly regarded university for mathematics :) (P.S. I'm in high school, so I won't be going there anyways)

Comment: @JohnMa I agree, that's why I needed to post it here. It's oddly phrased and obviously not well-defined...but I tried to take it naively

Comment: Or do it this way. Restrict the domain to $C_c(\mathbb R)$ (still with the $L^2$ norm).  Then the map is well defined and you can still show that it is unbounded.

Comment: I think the exercise (and the question) actually meant  $\mathscr{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ instead of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: If so, the exercise is asking for a counterexample to show that $f \mapsto f(0)$ is not continue with respect to the (pseudo-)norm  $\Vert \phantom{f} \Vert_2$ of $\mathscr{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$.  One simple counterexemple would be: Let $f=0$  and, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n>0$, let $f_n=\chi_{[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]}$. It is easy to see that $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \vert f_n-f\vert^2 d\lambda = \frac{2}{n} \to 0$, so $f_n \to f$ with respect to $\Vert \phantom{f} \Vert_2$. But, for all $n$, $f_n(0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$. So $f \mapsto f(0)$ is not continue (w.r.t.  $\Vert \phantom{f} \Vert_2$).

Answer (score 6):

A precise way to present this problem would be as follows:

> The linear functional $f\mapsto f(0)$, defined on the linear subspace $L^2(\mathbb{R})\cap C(\mathbb{R})$, is not continuous in the $L^2$ norm.

(Hence, it cannot be extended to a continuous linear functional on $L^2$, no matter how we try to make sense of $f(0)$ there.)

The proof of the statement follows by considering the sequence $f_n(x)=\max(0, 1-n|x|)$, which satisfies $f_n(0)=1$ for all $n$ despite $f_n\to0$ in $L^2$ norm.

Comment: (One can always consider continuous functions on pseudo-metric spaces, of course!)

Comment: Yes, and I'd go further, to note that $f\to f(0)$ is a continuous linear functional on $C^o(\mathbb R)$ (the latter with the sup norm), and that the injection $C^o(\mathbb R)\to L^2(\mathbb R)$ is continuous with dense image, but/and that functional does _not_ extend...